# gluster geo-replication xsync

Tags: geo, glusterfs

Help with a solution to the problem. Set geo replication to synchronize files (about 5m).
After starting the synchronization occurs. But after copying files 80K runs out of space on tmpfs (/ run).
It is normal for geo replication or not?

Perhaps something I did wrong?

dpkg -l | grep glust

```
ii  glusterfs-client                   3.5.3-1                       amd64        clustered file-system (client package)
ii  glusterfs-common                   3.5.3-1                       amd64        GlusterFS common libraries and translator modules
ii  glusterfs-server                   3.5.3-1                       amd64        clustered file-system (server package)
```

gluster volume geo-replication stgrec01 172.16.10.3::stgrec01_slave status

```
MASTER NODE     MASTER VOL    MASTER BRICK            SLAVE                          STATUS           CHECKPOINT STATUS    CRAWL STATUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------------------
msk-m9-stg28    stgrec01      /xfs1tb/recordings01    172.16.10.3::stgrec01_slave    faulty     N/A                  N/A
msk-m9-stg29    stgrec01      /xfs1tb/recordings01    172.16.10.3::stgrec01_slave    Passive    N/A                  N/A
```

df -H

```
rootfs                                                    50G         2,2G   46G            5% /
udev                                                      11M            0   11M            0% /dev
tmpfs                                                    420M         420M     0          100% /run
```

ls xsync | wc -l

```
84956
```

Answer (score 0):

As you posted, The `df -H` is showing the tmpfs 100% used. Try to clear it before proceeding.